# Why is git stash leaving my working directory in a dirty state?

Tags: git

```
$ git add -A

$ git status 
... 
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   Source/ConfigGeneratorTests/ConfigGeneratorTests.csproj
        (and 20 other files) 

$ git stash save
Saved working directory and index state WIP on ...

$ git status 
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   Source/ConfigGeneratorTests/ConfigGeneratorTests.csproj
        (and 20 other files)
```

After a `stash save`, a file that was added to the index is now not stashed and not saved in the index. Is there a reason for this? I've used `stash` many times and never seen it do this.

Comment: Have you tried `git stash save --no-keep-index`? This should cause all of your changes to be removed from the working copy and stashed in `save`

Comment: That wouldn't have helped I think, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/28662189/30946

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is really your case, but recently I had the same behavior of git repo (Windows, ASP.NET MVC project) after my collegue has pushed **.gitattributes** file to github where the line-endings setting was changed (for example from **as-is** to **checkout windows-style, commit linux-style**).

So **git stash** produced no error but gave no effect at the same time (modified files appeared in status and stayed there until I commit them). Removing **.gitattributes** worked for me.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. I'll remove my answer. I commented out `* text=auto` in my `.gitattributes` and the problem went away. This line ending stuff is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered another reason for `git stash` failing to leave a clean working directory: I was accessing my git repo through a samba mount.

A bunch of files suddenly had execute permissions set, which showed up as a difference.  **Neither `git stash` nor `git reset --hard` could restore the permissions, probably because the client machine that was doing the samba mounting couldn't actually affect the permissions.**

Logging in to the server and accessing the git repository directly on its native file system made the problem go away.